# R devtools::install_github / install_bitbucket - vignettes not installed when not building

Tags: r, installation, devtools

I have a R package on bitbucket including built vignettes in `doc` folder. Building the vignettes requires access to local database, therefore the user cannot built the vignette at his/her machine. Although it says

```
** installing vignettes
```

during

```
devtools::install_bitbucket("uniks_ines/dexr@default", build=F)
```

vignettes' HTML files are not copied to the library location, and `browseVignettes("dexR")` gives

> No vignettes found by browseVignettes("dexR")

Any idea why vignettes are not installed?

Comment: Where in the package directory are the pre-built vignettes: `inst/doc/` or `vignettes/`?

Comment: `vignettes` contains the `*.Rmd` files (and directories `css`, `png`, and `js`), and `inst/doc` contains `*.html`, `*.R`, and `*.Rmd` files.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the help page for the function (`?remotes::install_bitbucket`), you'll see in the "Usage" section that the default value for the `build_opts` argument is

```
build_opts = c("--no-resave-data", "--no-manual", "--no-build-vignettes")
```

You can solve your problem via

```
library(devtools)
install_bitbucket("uniks_ines/dexr@default",
                  build_opts = c("--no-resave-data", "--no-manual"))
```

The changes I have made to your initial command are removing `build = FALSE` and removing the `"--no-build-vignettes"` element of the `build_opts` vector.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. Unfortunately, you misunderstood the problem: I clearly state that I do not want to (or more specific: cannot) _build_ the vignettes (as this requires database access which is usually not present during installation) but want to make sure already built vignettes are copied to the installation location.

Comment: @SaschaH Apologies; you're right, your question is quite clear and I should not have misread it. Are the pre-built vignettes you need in `inst/doc/` or `vignettes/`?